# printing data in python error (list indices must be integers, not str)

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the data. This is my code:

```
print 'The first 5 tweets for \"{}\":\n'.format(keywords[0])
for txt in k1_tweets_processed[0:5]:
print txt['text']
print
```

This is my error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-e74a15accb5b> in <module>()
  5 print 'The first 5 tweets for \"{}\":\n'.format(keywords[0])
  6 for txt in k1_tweets_processed[0:5]:
 ----> 7     print txt['text']
  8 print
  9 

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: `print txt['text']` , you should use this if you want to access dictionary, not list.

Answer (score 2):

```
print txt['text']
```

You are clearly passing a `string` as index, but list indices should be `int`, not `string`.

You should use this if you want to access dictionary, not list.

As both you and the error message saying this is a list, no need to use that line.

You already have list element in `txt`. So, try:

```
print txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 7 with

```
print txt
```

It is likely you've already selected the text strings that you want using the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the contents of k1_tweets_processed you should do something like this:

```
for txt in k1_tweets_processed[0:5]:
    print txt
    print
```

The for loop will assign the variable txt to the current value of k1_tweets_processed, then execute the two print statements for each value.